# How to save a TextView background changed on click

Tags: android, background, textview, save, sharedpreferences

Hei guys, i'm new with android and i've been searching everywhere for an example on how can i save (even if i exit the app) the background color of a TextView that it's changed on click with SharedPreferences or anything else.

and use it with this code

```
Da = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dreaptaDA);       
    Nu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stangaNU);        
    Da.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {                                       
                Da.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
                Nu.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Gray);
        }
    });

    Nu.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                Nu.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                Da.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Gray);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get textview background color and put int in SharePreference

```
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable)textView.getBackground();
int i = cd.getColor();
SharePreference prefs = getSharedPreferences("db",0);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putInt("color", i);
edit.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
int i = cd.getColor();
SharePreference prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // no need to have
// named preferences - call this from an activity or other context
prefs.edit().putInt("color", i).commit();
```

The `this` means you are in some class that extends context.

Then when you need the color

```
int col = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("color",DEFAULT_COLOR);
```

where `DEFAULT_COLOR` is an int you define as a final field.